# Printing out a box

Tags: java

I want to try and print out a box that looks like:

```
+---+---+
|       |
+       +
|       |
+---+---+
```

but I am unsure on how to print out the right side.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        System.out.print("+---");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {

            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.println("+                   +");
                System.out.println("|                   |");

            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        System.out.print("+---");
    }
```

x represents the width of the box, and y represents the height.

---

This will give me the right output if I have a preset width, but I want to edit the box so I can change the width.

Comment: You should print the lines `|          |` with one for loop

Comment: Think of it line-by-line. When you are printing the left side you need to also print the right side.

Comment: Unless you use escape sequences to move the cursor ^^

Comment: "x represents the width of the box, and y represents the width." - you probably meant "y represents the height" right ?

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant.

Comment: What you're doing now doesn't make any sense. Imagine the terminal as a printer, with paper. You move left→right, newline, left→right, newline,... Print it the way a real printer would.

Comment: @MightyPork I'm afraid a lot of developers today have never seen a dot-matrix printer at work.

Comment: @biziclop that's sad, they were so cool! And fun, see watch?v=pX4tBIwhOqY xD

Comment: I want to make it print, so I can change the value of the width. Is there a way to make it print so I can add an "x" number of blank spaces like "    " then print the right side border?

Comment: In the example you provided, what values do x and y have?

Comment: I'm using 5 for both the width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Square {

    int heightInLines = 5;

    void printLine(int x){
        if(x == 1 || x == heightInLines){
            for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i ++){
                if(i == 1 || i == 5 || i == 9) System.out.print("+");
                else System.out.print("-");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }else if(x % 2 == 0) System.out.println("|       |");
        else System.out.println("+       +");

    }

    void print(){
        for(int i = 1; i <= heightInLines; i++)
            printLine(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Square().print();

    }
}
```

Note that this is not a general solution i.e you can't print squares of any size. But it prints what you are asking for plus it's easy and a good practice for you to modify the code to make it print squares of all sizes (maybe by passing arguments in the `print()` method or in the constructor. Up to you :) )

Answer (score 0):

Draw several examples. Decide what parts are common and what parts repeat. The repeating parts are the most interesting, because they will become loops in your code. In your case, you will have both vertical and horizontal repeating parts. The vertical parts will be in an outer loop (since you have to print top to bottom) while the horizontal repeats will be part of an inner loop (printing left to right). Once you have several examples, use a different colored pencil or pen to draw lines marking where the repeats occur. One iteration of a loop (either inner or outer) is responsible for printing/writing all the characters in just one instance of the repeating part. It is extremely likely that you will have parts (both horizontal and vertical) that are NOT part of a repeat. Those will need to be done before or after the appropriate loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // init to whatever you want
    int x = 3; // width
    int y = 5; // height

    // prepare the lines
    // beginning 
    String width = "+";
    String plus = "+";
    String pipe = "|";

    // build the repeating unit of
    // of the line that comes at the top/bottom
    for (int i=0; i<x-1; i++) {
        width += "-";
    }
    String tmp = width;
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x+1; j++) {
            plus += " ";
            pipe += " ";
        }
        width += tmp;
    }

    // add the "closing" char at the end of the line
    width += "+";
    plus += "+";
    pipe += "|";

    // draw top
    System.out.println(width);
    // draw middle
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            System.out.println(plus);
        else
            System.out.println(pipe);
    }
    // draw bottom
    System.out.println(width);
```

**Prints:**

```
+--+--+--+--+
|            |
+            +
|            |
+            +
|            |
+--+--+--+--+
```